# paintComponent always update rectangle

Tags: java, swing, paintcomponent, rectangles

I have some problem using rectangle

here my code :

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.*;
public class square
{
    JFrame fr=new JFrame("square");
    Random acak=new Random();
    JScrollPane sc;
    int tinggi,lebar;
    JTabbedPane tab=new JTabbedPane();
    square()
    {   
        fr.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        fr.setLocation(0,0);
        fr.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        fr.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,1));
        tab.addTab("Panel1",new panel1());
        tab.addTab("Panel2",new panel2());
        fr.add(tab);    
        fr.show();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new square();
    }
}
class panel1 extends JPanel
{
    panel1()
    {
    }
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g3)
    {
        int x=(int)(Math.random()*500);
        int y=(int)(Math.random()*500);
        g3.setColor(Color.red);
        g3.fillRect(x,y,100,100);
    }
}
class panel2 extends JPanel
{
    panel2()
    {
    }
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g2)
    {
        int x=(int)(Math.random()*500);
        int y=(int)(Math.random()*500);
        g2.setColor(Color.blue);
        g2.fillRect(x,y,100,100);
    }
}
```

i using coordinate and size by random

if I switch the tab, the coordinate and size of rectangle always change.

how to make and coordinate only in first time ???

Comment: Don't create/change the paint state (x, y) in the `paintComponent` method. Set it like in the constructor, and just _use_ it in the `paintComponent` method.

Comment: can you make any example ???

Comment: Just make `int x, y` fields of the panel class, and then initialize them in the constructor `public panel() { x = .., y = .. }`, then use the x and y in the paint method. If you don't understand fields and constructors, I highly recommend going over Java basics before working with GUIs

Comment: Sorry I don't have my IDE open.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here :

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.*;
public class square
{
    JFrame fr=new JFrame("square");
    Random acak=new Random();
    JScrollPane sc;
    int tinggi,lebar;
    JTabbedPane tab=new JTabbedPane();
    gambar()
    {   
        fr.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        fr.setLocation(0,0);
        fr.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        fr.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,1));
        tab.addTab("Panel1",new panel1());
        tab.addTab("Gambar",new panel2());
        fr.add(tab);    
        fr.show();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new square();
    }
}
class panel1 extends JPanel
{
    int x,y;
    panel1()
    {
        x=(int)(Math.random()*500);
        y=(int)(Math.random()*500);
    }
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g3)
    {

        g3.setColor(Color.red);
        g3.fillRect(x,y,x,y);
    }
}
class panel2 extends JPanel
{
    int x,y;
    panel2()
    {
        x=(int)(Math.random()*500);
        y=(int)(Math.random()*500);
    }
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g2)
    {

        g2.setColor(Color.blue);
        g2.fillRect(x,y,x,y);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Start by taking a look at [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) to understand how painting works.

Basically, when ever the system thinks your component needs to be updated, your `paintComponent` method will be called (indirectly) and it is expected to render the CURRENT state of the component.

Painting may occur for any number of reasons, most of which you don't have any control over.

Instead of calculating the state of the rectangle in the `paintComponent` method, have a method which you can control yourself which does this and have the `paintComponent` method simply do the painting.